# GhostScript - get ink_cov from top 5pt?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to get the ink coverage from the top 5pt from an PDF.
Most of the times, this command will give me equal result across many different PDFs:

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=ink_cov -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -g36340x5 "12345.pdf" | grep CMYK
```

That gives me a result like 0.02477.
But sometimes, I get completely different results, like 0.57318

I can admit that I'm not entirely sure that -g36340x5 means top 5pt. Is it maybe the bottom 5pt?
If I run the following command, I would think that the crop.pdf would show me what I want the ink coverage for, but it just shows me blank pdf.

```
gs -o crop.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -g36340x5 -f 12345.pdf
```

But if I run this command, the crop.pdf shows me the part I would like to get ink coverage for:

```
gs -o crop.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -g36340x6120 -c "[/CropBox [0 607 3634 612] /PAGES pdfmark" -f 12345.pdf
```

But even with that, when trying go execute this command with ink_cov-device, I get very different results on similar pdf's:

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=ink_cov -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -g36340x6120 -c "[/CropBox [0 607 3634 612] /PAGES pdfmark" -f 12345.pdf
```

All my pdf's are upside-down.

What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards
Niclas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-g sets the media size **in pixels**, it makes no attempt to relocate the content on the media. Since PostScript co-ordinates have 0.0 at bottom left, you are only looking at the bottom 5 pixels of the output.

Your third example uses pdfwrite to create a PDF file where the cropbox covers the area you are interested in. However, by default Ghostscript uses the MediaBox when rendering. If you want to use the CropBox then you need to add -dUseCropBox to your command line.  If you don't do that (as your last command does not) then it will still be checking the same content as the original PDF.

You either need to set a media size which matches the are you are interested in, **and** translate the page origin (which will be hard to do, as it will mean altering the PDF interpreter, how are you at programming in PostScript ?) or you need to create a new PDF with the CropBox, as you have done above, then process that PDF file with the inkcov device, but add -dUseCropBox (and discard the now redundant -g)

You'd probably find it easier to see what's going on if you render to screen instead of using inkcov, then you can change parameters and see what effect they have. Once you are convinced you are working with the area you want, then you can switch ot the inkcov device.